# Hessian of a function at the critical points

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory, hessian-matrix

Let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $p\in M$ is a critical point of it.

The Hessian of $f$ at a critical point $p$ is a symmetric bilinear form $\operatorname{Hess} f_p$ s.t. $\forall v,w\in T_pM$, 
    $$\operatorname{Hess} f_p(v,w)=V_p(W(f)),$$
    where $V,W$ are the extensions of $v$ and $w$ to vector fields such that $V_p=v$ and $W_p=w$. Let the critical set of $f$ contains a submanifold $C$. Put a Riemannian metric on $M$ and $\forall p\in C$ consider the decomposition  $$T_pM=T_pC\oplus T^{\perp}_pC.$$ Let $v\in T_pC$ and $w\in T^\perp_pC$. Then show that $$\operatorname{Hess} f_p(v,w)=0.$$

I would appreciate any comment

Comment: Have you considered any examples?  For instance, when doing Morse Theory a common example is the height function on a torus.  If you situate the torus on its end, the height function has four nondegenerate critical ponts, but if you lay it down like a donut normally sites, the height function has two critical submanifolds that are circles.  Try to calculate the hessian at a point in one of those circles.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I tried a more simple one which is the function from $R^3$ whose preimage is the cylinders. Then the Z-axes is the set of the critical points. In this example the restriction of $w(f)$ on Z-axes is zero and so the Hessian!
Now is there any point in the example of torus?

Comment: I think if your function is already a quadratic form, you might get $Wf \equiv 0$.  Don't have time to think it through right now, but it might be due to Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions.  Try $f(x,y) = (1-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)$.  This has a circle in the $xy$-plane as a critical submanifold.  Then let $W = x \partial_x + y \partial_y$ and $V = x\partial_y - y \partial_x$ and see what you get.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang My function is not necessarily quadratic. But you mentioned a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to C$ represent the tangent vector $v$. That is, $\gamma(0)=p$, and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$. Let $W$ be any extension of the tangent vector $w$ to a neighborhood of $p$. Then we have $$W_{\gamma(t)}(f)=0$$ for every $t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon),$ as $\gamma(t)$ is a critical point. By your definition of the Hessian, it now follows immediately that $\mathrm{Hess}f_p(v,w)=0.$

Note that the assumption $w\in T_p^\perp C$ is irrelevant here. This makes sense, as the Hessian of a function at a critical point is well-defined without any Riemannian metric or a connection (as implied by your definition).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution!