# Questions on the Hessian matrix on the unit sphere $\mathcal S^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, hessian-matrix

Let $\mathcal S^2:=\{(x,y,z)\;\vert \; x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ be the unit sphere and $f\in C^2(\mathcal S^2)$ with $f(x,y,z)=f(x)$. Moreover, assume that $N=(1,0,0)$ and $S=(-1,0,0)$ denote respectively the North and the South Pole of the sphere. Our professor wrote the other day this:

> $\begin{equation*} \nabla^2 f \big \vert_{N,S}=\begin{pmatrix}
>  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y
>  \partial z}\\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial y} &
>  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} \end{pmatrix} \end{equation*}\quad$
> since $\nabla f\big \vert_{N,S}=0 \quad (*)$

However, I have some trouble understanding $(*)$. My questions are:

1. The fact that $\nabla f\big \vert_{N,S}=0 $ indicates that the North and the South Pole are critical points for $f$. How do we know that?
2. Why does the Hessian matrix has this form? It seems to me that some sort of parametrization has been used here but I don't see how we conclude this matrix.
3. Is the particular form of the Hessian related to the fact that $\nabla f\big \vert_{N,S}=0 $ or is it independent on that?

EDIT (after @Arctic Char comments): Using the parametrization

$x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}, \quad y=y,\quad z=z$

we write $f(x,y,z)=\tilde f(y,z).\;$ Then, the gradient of $\tilde f$ is given by: $\nabla \tilde f=(\frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial z})=(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}},\frac{-z}{\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}})$ which vanishes at $(\pm 1,0,0)$. The Hessian matrix is actually the Hessian of $\tilde f$.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

I apologize if these questions are too silly but it's been ages since I did some calculations of that kind and I have forgotten some stuff. Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. There is no condition on $f$, so it is simply false that $\nabla f|_{N,S}  =0$. For 2. I assume that they are using the parametrization $(y,z) \mapsto (\pm \sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}, y, z)$, $+$ around $N$ and $-$ around $S$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I think he mentioned that $f(x,y,z)=f(x)$ but I wasn't sure if that contributes in the vanishing of the first derivatives, this is why omitted it. Would such a condition imply the first item?

Comment: Yes it would. You may try to verify it using the local parametrization in my previous comment.

Comment: @ArcticChar I just edited my post. I'd be glad if you could verify the calculations. Thanks!

Comment: What's $\tilde f$?

Comment: @ArcticChar The function $f$ after the parametrization. I wanted to stress that now is a function only in terms of $y,z$...

Comment: Can you write down $\tilde f$ explicitly? As of now I don't see how you calculate $\frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial y}$ (but I assume you are in the right direction).

Comment: @ArcticChar I thought that $f(x,y,z)=f(\pm \sqrt{1-y^2-z^2},y,z)=\tilde f(y,z)$. Is this abuse of notation or misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes that's correct,now your derivative has nothing to do with $f$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I guess there is a relation though the definition of $\tilde f$ via $f$, but it's not clear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that $f(x, y, z) = f(x)$ depends only on $x$. Around $N = (1,0,0)$, one can parameterize the sphere as
$$ (y, z) \mapsto (\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2} , y, z),$$
so locally $f$ is given by
$$ \tilde f (y, z) = f(x(y, z)) = f( \sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}).$$
Hence

$$ \left( \frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial z}\right) = -f' \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}},  \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}}\right)$$
is zero when $(y, z) = (0,0)$.

For the Hessian: away from a critical point, the Hessian of a function is actually not well defined, unless you specify some Riemannian metric. Please see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492702/hessian-of-a-function-at-the-critical-points), or this [article](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/hessian.pdf) for more details.